# why interface variables are always static and why not abstract class are always static?

Tags: java, oop

I know interface variables are always static because we can't make object of interface. But why not abstract class variables are always static? We cant make object of abstract class too

Comment: I would guess that interface was more about methods (behaviour) than fields (state), and fields were introduced just to make organizing constants easier. I suspect that if enums ware introduced in first version of Java we wouldn't even have constants in interfaces.

Comment: You might want to read ['Interface' Considered Harmful](http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2015/01/08/InterfaceConsideredHarmful.html) for more background.

Comment: @Steve C, do they have an "unsigned considered harmful" as well? ;)

Comment: What you want to know is "why can't interfaces have non-static fields?", not "why must all fields in an interface be static?".

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between interfaces and abstract classes is that - **interfaces are just contracts**, they are for specifying the *signature* of the methods that their subsequent concrete implementation *must have*, and all the methods in an interface are implicitly `abstract`.

In contrast, **abstract classes are classes**, they can have non-abstract methods with default implementation.

As quoted from [JLS for the definition of an interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html):

> An interface declaration introduces a new reference type whose members are classes, interfaces, constants, and abstract methods. This type has no implementation, but otherwise unrelated classes can implement it by providing implementations for its abstract methods.

and [the definition of an abtract class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1.1):

> An abstract class is a class that is incomplete, or to be considered incomplete.

While interfaces do not do anything except specifying the pattern of the classes that implement them, abstract classes can do more - you can define their behavior - hence you can actually provide concrete implementation of their methods as well as defining their states (i.e. instance variables).

Answer (score 0):

This is because the field of abstract class is then inherited by all subclasses and can be used by them. So, you can implement methods in your abstract class that deal with the logic related to such fields. You can think of an abstract class as a partially finished implementation; because it is partially finished, it cannot be constructed before it's completed by a subclass.

Answer (score 0):

It is all explained by the `implements` vs. `extends` keywords: you're *implementing* the functionalities of an interface but are *extending* the capabilities of a (potentially abstract) class.

As you're *extending*, you inherit all of its fields and method in your instance.
You have instances of an abstract class as soon as you extend it: you're adding/changing functionalities to it, whereas an interface is merely an empty shell that you have to "fill in" with a behaviour.